# Chrome 75.x. latest update sets: internal-input-suggested. This leads to smaller font

Tags: css, google-chrome

Sometimes the autofill of Chrome sets an extra shadow pseudo class to my input, that uses the style:

```
<div pseudo="-internal-input-suggested" id="placeholder" style="display: block !important;">a....od@gmail.com</div>
```

It has the browser intern CSS of:

```
input::-internal-input-suggested, textarea::-internal-input-suggested {
    font: 400 11px system-ui !important;
}
```

I don't know why, but I just cannot overwrite this. How would you fix it?

This problem leads to the wrong using of font-family and font-size:

[image] (It's way too small)

[image]

This does not work:

```
input::-internal-input-suggested {
    font: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is awful. It is totally hiding a date widget in my app.

Comment: Star it, to follow the issue and rise attention: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991157

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Chrome from changing font when autofilling username/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026043/how-to-prevent-chrome-from-changing-font-when-autofilling-username-password). See my answer there – tl;dr; this is intentionally not overrideable anymore :/

Comment: @ThibaudColas it's very similar to my problem, but without showing the pseudo class. Nonetheless, I am still going to accept this as a duplication.