# How can I remove the styles from the pseudo element -internal-input-suggested?

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium

As of the version *76.0.3809.100*  of Google Chrome, I have a new pseudo element to autocomplete the inputs. I want the autocomplete function but I need remove the styles by default.

```
<div pseudo="-internal-input-suggested" id="placeholder" style="display: block 
 !important;">
    myEMail@gmail.com
</div>
```

**Styles applied by default on Chrome:**

```
input::-internal-input-suggested, textarea::-internal-input-suggested {
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial !important;
}
```

I'm trying overwrite with the same *input::-internal-input-suggested, textarea::-internal-input-suggested* on my css but I can not.

Answer (score 3):

Carlos. This is Chrome bug [#991157](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991157), [#953689](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=953689) with status WontFix.

The workaround I found is using `:-webkit-autofill` and `:-webkit-autofill:first-line`

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:first-line {
    font-size: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    /* font-family: font name; */
}
```

Comment: I think this is for filled autofill. OP is refering to the state when the users hover autofill options.